# How to show cropped image on same page

Tags: php, image, jcrop

I want to be able to crop a file three time (so you have a big, medium and small image). The problem right now is that the JCrop is working. Uploading the file works, and you can actually "crop" the file. The problem is that the cropped file is not shown when pressed on the submit button.

As you can see in the code I use a function ShowCrop to keep things tidy, the function is called before the submit form begins. When I run the page I see nothing (no form, no image). Something obviously goes wrong that this function.

I am a beginning PHP scripter, and I am sure there are a lot of faults in this script. Please remind me of those so I can learn!

Here's the code:

```
<?php
//Original upload
if(isset($_POST['upload']))  {
    $name = '_original';
    $path_info = pathinfo($_FILES['afbeelding']['name']);
    $file_extension = $path_info["extension"];
    $newname = $path_info['filename'].$name.".".$file_extension;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['afbeelding']['tmp_name'], 'images/' . $newname);}
            ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.noobtutorials.nl/voorbeelden/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $( function () {
            $('img').Jcrop({
                setSelect: [150, 150, 500, 500],
                onSelect: function (c) {
                    $("input[name=x]").val(c.x);
                    $("input[name=y]").val(c.y);
                    $("input[name=w]").val(c.w);
                    $("input[name=h]").val(c.h);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php echo $newname ?>
        Big format:
        <form method="post" action="upload.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="x" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="y" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="w" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="h" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="fextension" value="<?php echo $file_extension ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value=<?php echo $newname ?> />
            <input type="hidden" name="image" value="images/<?php echo $_FILES['afbeelding'][$newname]; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Crop image!" />
        </form>
        <?php
        echo '<img src="getimage.php?file=images/' . $newname . '">';
    }
    phpinfo();
}
else if(isset($_POST['x'])) //GROOT -> MIDDEL
{
    ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.noobtutorials.nl/voorbeelden/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $( function () {
            $('img').Jcrop({
                setSelect: [150, 150, 500, 500],
                onSelect: function (c) {
                    $("input[name=x]").val(c.x);
                    $("input[name=y]").val(c.y);
                    $("input[name=w]").val(c.w);
                    $("input[name=h]").val(c.h);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    echo $_POST['name'];
    showCrop($_POST['fextension']);
    //echo '<img src="getimage.php?file=images/' . $_POST['name'] . '">';
    ?> Middel formaat:
    <form method="post" action="upload.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="x" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="y" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="w" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="h" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="image" value="images/<?php echo $_FILES['afbeelding'][$newname]; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Crop image!" />
        </form><?php
}

function showCrop($ext){
$targ_w = $_POST['w'];
$targ_h = $_POST['h'];
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$src = $_POST['image'];
  switch($ext)
  {
      case 'jpg';
      $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
      $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

      imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
      $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

      //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
      imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);
      break;
      case 'png';
      $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
      $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

      imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
      $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
      move_uploaded_file($dst_r, 'images/' ."test". $newname);
      break;
exit;             
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Simply a blank page. Only the form (since a minute) and the name of the file, and the middel formaat: text is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rewritten the logic of the code so it'll automatically reload the page until each size/crop has been completed.

This isn't pretty code and is lacking a lot of additional functions (database, security, etc), but it demonstrates how you can achieve what you need (hopefully).

```
<?php

// Resize image and return filename
function saveCrop($source, $destination) {

    // Get extension
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($source, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // Resize/Crop image
    switch($ext)
    {
        case 'jpg';
            $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
            $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);
            imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r, 0, 0, $_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $_POST['w'], $_POST['h'], $_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);
            imagejpeg($dst_r, $destination);
            return true;
            break;

        case 'png';
            $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($source);
            $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);
            imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r, 0, 0, $_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $_POST['w'], $_POST['h'], $_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);
            imagepng($dst_r, $destination); 
            return true;
            break;

        default:
            die('Invalid file extension: ' . $ext);
    }
}

// Save uploaded file to web server for future processing
if ( isset($_FILES['uploaded-file']))
{
    // Check for valid file type
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['uploaded-file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if ( ! in_array($ext, array('jpg', 'png')))
    {
        die('Unsupported file type');
    }
    $source_file = 'images/original-' . $_FILES['uploaded-file']['name'];

    if ( ! move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded-file']['tmp_name'], $source_file))
    {
        die('Unable to move uploaded file (possibly due to write permissions)');
    }

    // Set target file
    $target_file = 'images/large-' . $_FILES['uploaded-file']['name'];

}
// Process crop/resize requests
elseif (isset($_POST['x']))
{
    $source_file = $_POST['source'];
    $target_file = $_POST['target'];

    saveCrop($source_file, $target_file);

    // No more cropping is required after the small image
    if (substr($target_file, 0, 12) == 'images/small')
    {
        header('Location: completed.php');
    }
    else
    {
        // Determine new source file
        $source_file = $target_file;

        // Determine new target file
        $target_file = str_replace(
            array('images/medium', 'images/large', 'images/original'),
            array('images/small', 'images/medium', 'images/large'),
            $target_file
        );
    }
}
?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.noobtutorials.nl/voorbeelden/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( function () {
        $('img').Jcrop({
        setSelect: [150, 150, 500, 500],
            onSelect: function (c) {
                $("input[name=x]").val(c.x);
                $("input[name=y]").val(c.y);
                $("input[name=w]").val(c.w);
                $("input[name=h]").val(c.h);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="x" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="y" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="w" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="h" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="source" value="<?php echo $source_file; ?>" />
        <input type="text" name="target" value="<?php echo $target_file; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Crop" />
    </form>

    <img src="<?php echo $source_file; ?>" id="img">
```

Comment: When you upload the file (on another page) that field is set, it all works. It all goes wrong that the second time (so when $_POST['x'] is set).

Comment: Okay, your `showCrop()` function has two calls to `exit;` calls which will instantly stop your request (therefore potentially giving you a blank screen). It's also possible that the `switch()` statement is not matching the `case 'jpg':` and `case 'png';` blocks. Add a `default:` section to the `switch()` statement to make sure that isn't causing the issue.

Comment: The switch statements do match, I've tested that. Ive now put exit; behind the last break;. Not working. I just need to create the cropped image (with imagepng/imagejpg perhaps?) and save it to a directory and then echo the image with <img src ?

Comment: You were right, somehow the extension didn't work out. I edited the OP, right now I get two errors: Warning: imagecreatefrompng() [function.imagecreatefrompng]: 'images/' is not a valid PNG file in test/upload.php on line 114

Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in test/upload.php on line 118

Comment: The value you're submitting for `$_POST['image']` is a string, and while it might be a filename, your code isn't loading the actual image from the server so those functions will not work until you correct those issues.

Comment: But when I upload the file (called original file) I need to crop it, and that cropped file (the biggest image) cannot be created before you press the button, therefore it would never be able to load it at showcrop...

Comment: Do the big, medium and small images need to be cropped separately, or should the code be creating three images/files using the same crop marks?

Comment: Seperately. When you crop the original image you get to crop that image into a medium image and that image will be able to be cropped to a small image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45209/discussion-between-kirk-beard-and-user2014780)